# Ignore file- and directory-variables when using "emacs -Q"?

Tags: git, directory-local-variables, file-local-variables

I am using `emacs -Q` as editor for git, because my startup is too heavy for "quick editing" use and using `emacsclient` will hang when git is invoked with `M-x shell-command`. However, as a consequence I keep getting prompted to confirm directory variables, when I have custom variables in a repository.

Is there some way to make `emacs -Q` ignore directory variables, it doesn't know about?

Comment: My apologies if you've already heard this a thousand times, but the [magit](https://magit.vc) interface for git is amazing, and would resolve all these niggling little conflicts

Comment: @Tyler Powerful or not, using the cli tools directly is more so. And I'd rather use the tools that work for every project, rather than learning the UI of yet another wrapper. With the exception of `git gui`, which allows comitting only specific lines for a cleaner history, I am using non-cli tools only for visualization/investigation purposes (e.g. `M-x magit-blame` or `M-! gitk --branches`).

Comment: If I understand you, you've got directory variables, which means you are editing your files in Emacs? Then you open `M-x shell` to interact with git on the command line, and you want to open `emacs -Q` from git running in your `M-x shell` terminal? You can call `emacsclient` from `M-x shell`, so debugging that might be easier than convincing `emacs -Q` to ignore directory variables.

Comment: @Tyler The files are edited in Emacs. For interaction with `git` I use both `M-x shell-command = M-!` and a separate terminal. Invoked from `M-x shell-command`, using `git config core.editor emacsclient` causes a dead-lock.

Comment: This works for me. Have you started the emacs daemon? In order for `emacsclient` to work, you need to call `(server-start)` from within emacs, or start emacs with the command `emacs --daemon`. That would be the most likely cause of a lock.

Comment: @Tyler I reconstructed the case that fails. The issues arise when accidentally invoking `emacsclient`, directly or indirectly through `git config core.editor emacsclient`, synchronously. This creates a deadlock, that requires killing the `emacsclient` executable. This happens when using `M-!` aka `M-x shell-command`, without making it asynchronous and thus is a frequent occurrence, when using the git cli directly from within emacs.